# Downloading Gzip'ed content with libcurl without deflating

Tags: libcurl

I want to retrieve webpages in their gzipped format, but instead of deflating it, I'd like to write the gzipped bytes to a file stream. Is this possible? If I don't send the correct accepts header for gzip, I get the normal html content, but if I do send the accepts gzip header, then it appears libcurl automatically defaltes it. Am I able to retrieve the original compressed bytes without the overhead of decompressing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in `Accept-Encoding: gzip` as a custom header with [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html), libcurl won't decompress it automatically. It will only automatically decompress gzip if you set [CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I did, I'm not sure about the default value, but I set TextTransfer to false as well.